# How to sort angular tabs created with material design using jquery ui sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-material

I was trying to create a way to sort (or arrange) [angular material tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/tabs) using jquery ui sortable. I tried using `ui.sortable` but it does not work with `md-tabs` because I get an error *multiple directives trying to create an isolate scope*.

Anyway, so I have been able to sort / arrange the tabs successfully with jquery ui sortable. Sharing it here in case someone else need it in future (because right there are 0 results for it on SO or any other site).

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to sort / arrange the tabs successfully with jquery ui sortable. If you have suggestions or improvements, please feel free to share it too!

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = ['Item #1', 'Item #2', 'Item #3', 'Item #4', 'Item #5']
    $scope.sort = function() {
      var tabs = $("#sortable").sortable({
        "items": "md-tab-item",
        "axis": "x",
        "start": function(event, ui) {
          ui.item.startPos = ui.item.index();
        },
        "stop": function(event, ui) {
          var oldIndex = ui.item.startPos;
          var newIndex = ui.item.index();
          var backward = oldIndex > newIndex;

          $scope.items.splice(newIndex + (backward ? 0 : 1), 0, $scope.items[oldIndex]);
          $scope.items.splice(oldIndex + (backward ? 1 : 0), 1);

          $timeout();
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom ng-init="sort()" id="sortable">
      <md-tab label="Tab: {{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          {{item}}
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to destroy the sortable when your directive scope is destroyed. I don't know whtat the empty timeout is for, but you should clean that up too.

Comment: @TJ thanks for the comments. The empty `$timeout` is a way of calling `$scope.apply()` safely. This is required because the digest cycle does trigger after drag-drop (jquery sortable), but calling an empty `$timeout` does that (with safety that no other digest cycle is running). Also regarding your second comment, can you please give me more details. I do not see any bugs?